# Java script: assign variables for text area comma separated values for each line

Tags: javascript, jsp

User will enter the data in textarea of html  as below

Praveen,23,Engineer
Ajay,29,Doctor
Aijaz,21,Plumber

I am able to split lines in jsp using below syntax

```
   String texts[] = new String(request.getParameter("textarea")).split("\\n");;
```

But I want comma separated values as variables for each iteration

1st iteration:

Belwo should be the contents of variables:

`var name[i]` should contain **Praveen**
`var age[i]` should contain **23**
`var profession[i]` should contain **Engineer**

2nd iteration:

`var name[i]` should contain **Ajay**
`var age[i]` should contain **29**
`var profession[i]` should contain **Doctor**

3rd iteration:

`var name[i]` should contain **Aijaz**
`var age[i]` should contain **21**
`var profession[i]` should contain **Plumber**

Kindly help in getting the correct code for this java script.

Comment: Then just split again on commas ?

Comment: String texts[] ... not javscript ... is this a java or javscript question?